# How to create a .json file from fetch API call response using fs.writeFile

Tags: javascript

I want to generate a .json file on my local project folder. I want to save the fetch API call response (which is an array of objects) into a .json file on my hard disc. Here is my code :

const fs = require('fs');

export default function getdirectory(token) {

```
return fetch(url, {
                  headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + token}
                })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .catch((err) =>{
                    console.log("ERORRRRRRRR @@@@@@" + err);
                })
                .then((response) =>   { 
                    //console.log(response);
                    var jsoncontent = JSON.stringify(response);
                    //console.log(jsoncontent);
                    fs.writeFileSync('files-to-cache.json', jsoncontent, function(err) {

                    if (err) 
                        {console.log("EROROROROROR ****" + err);}
                    else
                        { return response;}
                    });
                   // return response;
                })
                .catch((err) =>{
                    console.log("ERORRRRRRRR $$$$$$" + err);
                })
            };
```

When I run the code in vs code I get the following error:

**undefined is not a function (near '...fs.writeFileSync...')**

It seems that it happens because the data is not ready at the time of json file creation (asynchronous). Some web sites recommend setTimeOut function or sf.writeFileSync instead of sf.writeFile. I tried both, but still it doesn't work.
Would you please help me to resolve this problem?
Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are using the incorrect version of write file, there are two different types, see below:

The first is writeFileSync, this is synchronous, and will block the thread, meaning your script cannot continue until it is finished, but most importantly it doesn't accept a call back...

Try this instead:

```
  fs.writeFile('data.json', jsonData, 'utf8', (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('File created!`)
  })
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Lloyd for your guidance. I tried the code you provided, but unfortunately I still receive the same error : undefined is not a function (near '...fs.writeFile...')